# Insert multiple arrays in specific multidimensional array location with associated key

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

If you have two arrays with random number of keys:

```
$array1 = array(
  'one' => 'a',
  'two' => 'b',
);
$array2 = array(
  'minusone' => 'e',
  'zero' => 'd',
  'one' => 'a',
  'two' => 'b',
);
```

and then want to insert these two arrays:

```
$insert_1 = array( 'hello' => 'x' );
$insert_2 = array( 'world' => 'y' );
```

But you need to put them in a very specific place and you don't know the numeric key location, for this example, let's say between keys 'one' and 'two', so that the end results for the original arrays is:

```
 $array = array(
      'one' => 'a',
      'hello' => 'x',
      'world' => 'y',
      'two' => 'b',
);
$array2 = array(
  'minusone' => 'e',
  'zero' => 'd',
  'one' => 'a',
  'hello' => 'x'
  'world' => 'y',
  'two' => 'b',
);
```

Is this possible?

I tried using array_splice() but it requires a numeric key so I can't use:

```
array_splice( $array1, 'one', 0, $insert_1 );
array_splice( $array1, 'one', 0, $insert_2 );
array_splice( $array2, 'one', 0, $insert_1 );
array_splice( $array2, 'one', 0, $insert_2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of doing that.
one thing you can try is, first divide the main array up to the point where you want to insert another array, merge the $insert_1 and $insert_2 with divided 1st part and then merge the 2nd divided part to the modified array.

Here is the logic:

```
$array2 = array(
  'minusone' => 'e',
  'zero' => 'd',
  'one' => 'a',
  'two' => 'b',
);
$tempArray1 = array(
      'minusone' => 'e',
      'zero' => 'd',
);
$tempArray2 = array(
      'one' => 'a',
      'two' => 'b',
);
$tempArray3 = array_merge($tempArray1, $insert_1);
$changedArray = array_merge($tempArray3, $tempArray2);
```

here is an example of this function, use it as it is or change accordingly:

```
<?php 
$arr = array(
  'one' => 'a',
  'two' => 'b',
  'four' => 'd',
);

function addArrayAfter($mainArray, $key, $arrayToAdd){
    $tempArray = array();
    $tempArray2 = array();
    $splitHere = false;
    foreach($mainArray as $k => $v) {
        if($splitHere){
            $tempArray2[$k] = $v;
        } else {
            $tempArray[$k] = $v;
        }

        if($k == $key){
            $splitHere = true;
            $tempArray[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    $tempArray3 = array_merge($tempArray, $arrayToAdd);
    return array_merge($tempArray3, $tempArray2);
}

$insert_1 = array( 'hello' => 'x' );
$insert_2 = array( 'world' => 'y' );
$arr = addArrayAfter($arr, 'two', $insert_1);
$arr = addArrayAfter($arr, 'two', $insert_2);


print_r($arr);
?>
```

Comment: If this answer helped you, please share my blog: https://vny.xyz/ 
I started the blog for writing these types of information there, related to javascript, nodeJS, PHP, android.